# How create Makefile with sub-projects

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have no experience in creating makefiles. Until now, I used IDE to build projects.
I need to create a simple makefile for a project in C++ using a library / module written in C

The structure of my project looks like this:

```
app
  |-- main.cpp
  |-- config.h
  |-- module1
  |     |-- mod1.c
  |     └-- mod1.h
  |-- module2
  |     |-- mod2.c
  |     └-- mod2.h
  └-- module3
        |-- mod3.c
        └-- mod3.h
```

I created one makefile in the main directory and manually added module paths as the source.
`src = $(wildcard module1/*.c)$(wildcard module2/*.c)$(wildcard module2/*.c)`

Unfortunately, the compilation process ends with including error:

```
In file: mod1.c
No such file or directory 
#include <module2.h>
```

I guess it's because the modules are dependent on each other. So the source files of the library inlcude files from other modules in this way:

mod1.c:

```
#include "mod1.h"
#include <mod2.h>
#include <config.h>
```

I suppose this is a good and professional approach. My goal is to create a very simple makefile that builds the project in accordance with this structure and these assumptions.

Should each module have a separate makefile? How should it be organized?

I know "ugly" solutions like relativizing paths inside the library but I would like to do it "according to art".

I will be grateful for any hint or example.

Comment: You need something like `CFLAGS += -Imodule1 -Imodule2 -Imodule3`. That is, you need to tell the compiler where to look for the module header files. Alternatively the includes should include the sub-dir `#include "module2/mod2.h"`. I would personally go with the latter.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added CFLAGS but in this format: `-I./module1` I will check without `./`. Second solution is always an option but I would not like to change the original sources and interfere with the original idea.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Note that the latter is actually better practice (IMHO). Consider the case where two modules both have the same header file name (which can be common). With the Makefile approach it would be difficult to ensure the correct header is included. With the latter approach it is clear which header is being included.